# Mongo Prisma Client - query the child element array value. How to filter by value from the child array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, prisma

Example:

I have a schema , and I am using prisma as th ORM to communicate to mongodb

```
model Category {
id           String       @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
products     Product[]
}

type Product {
name                  String
popular               Boolean

}
```

collection would look like

```
 category =[
  {
    name: "Juice",
    products: [
      {
        name: "Mojito",
        popular: true,
      },
      {
        name: "Lemon mint",
        popular: false,
      },
    ],
  },

  {
    name: "Coffee",
    products: [
      {
        name: "Caramel",
        popular: true,
      },
      {
        name: " mint",
        popular: false,
      },
    ],
  }
];
```

question:
how to query category collection and filter out only the popular item

Result expected:

```
[
  {
    name: "Juice",
    products: [
      {
        name: "Mojito",
        popular: true,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "Coffee",
    products: [
      {
        name: "Caramel",
        popular: true,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

how do I achieve this Prisma Client for Mongo db.
I tried to use where clause with 'some' operator. but it doesnt' seem to be working.

```
 const categoriesWithPopularProduct = db.category.findMany({
    where: {
      products: {
        some: {
          popular: { equals: true },
        },
      },
    },
    
  });
```

The above query is returning all the products in the category. I want only the category with  only the products which are popular.

can anybody help me.?

Answer (score 0):

I use `aggregate` and `$filter` to extra all document with `popular: true`. Hope this help you:

```
const options = [
  {
    '$match': {
      'products.popular': true
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      'name': 1, 
      'products': {
        '$filter': {
          'input': '$products', 
          'as': 'item', 
          'cond': {
            '$eq': [
              '$$item.popular', true
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]

const categoriesWithPopularProduct = db.category.aggregate(options);
```